# fetch ITunes Search API GET

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can not understand what the problem is, I get a request through fetch, I try to see what comes, but nothing works

```
import React from 'react';

import './SearchLine.css';

export class SearchLine extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = { data: []}
    }


    MakeARequest(request) {
       fetch("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson",
            {
                mode:'no-cors'  
            }
        )
    .then(response => console.log(response));
   }
  componentDidMount() {
     this.MakeARequest('sia');
  }

  render() {
  return(
   <div>
    {this.state.data.length !==0?
        this.state.data.map(
            (data_iter, i) => {
                return(
                    <div
                        DATA={data_iter}
                        key={i}
                    />
                )
            }
        ): " "
    }
   </div>
);
}}
```

The status of the request is false in the browser console, nothing is displayed, I don’t know why, before the error crashed on CORS, but I registered "no-cors" in the fetch request, but nothing changes

[image: Error message screen image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding `mode: 'no-cors'` won’t make this work. Browsers by default block the CORS requests. Your code will only work if the server response with Access-Control-Allow-Origin, then the browser will not block the request and will allow your code to access response but if it doesn't send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in its responses then chrome won't allow your code to access the response from the site.